# Entity Framework Identity Column Negative Value

Tags: postgresql, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have an ASP.NET Core 1.0 web application that implements some REST web services which interact with a PostgreSQL database via Entity Framework Core.

In my model, I have a variety of code-first entity classes that utilize the following pattern:

```
[Key]
[DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
public int Id { get; set; }
```

Obviously this corresponds to an auto-incrementing unique key identity column in the database.

The trouble is that, undoubtedly due to some defect somewhere, occasionally for reasons I don't yet understand, the value of the Id is a very large negative integer.

```
-2147482645
```

Normally, they are well-behaved nicely ascending integer values starting at 1.

What could be causing it?

Comment: Nothing prevents someone from inserting such a number manually

Comment: My __very__ limited understanding of PostgreSQL is that the autoincrement data type is called `serial` or `bigserial`. Perhaps you should check what the migration is generating and if it's not what you want, use a `Column` attribute to specify the preferred data type. Incidentally, the current attributes you are using are superfluous. Your key property follows convention.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name yes but I'm not doing that. I am letting EF have full control of inserts.

Comment: @mike-brind thanks for the suggestion but the default behaviour is fine, there are some other circumstances in this specific, unusual case. And I'm not 100% sure what you mean by "superfluous."

Comment: Superfluous == not needed. Attributes are only needed if your classes or properties don't follow EF conventions. EF will see a property named Id as the primary key by convention. And if it is an int, there is no need to specify `DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)`. EF will apply that value generation strategy by default.

Comment: @mike-brind oh, that's cool. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out this issue had to do with calling `Update()` on the entity before it had even been inserted with a call to `Add()`. Naturally calling `Update()` on an non-inserted entity causes an exception to be thrown. But then catching the exception and using it as a flag that the entity needs to be added doesn't seem to be an option, as doing so consistently caused the negative Id value to be used on the subsequent insert. The solution involved detecting using other means that the entity didn't exist yet, and then properly calling `Add()` to insert it rather than using `Update()` as a default action.